# Shell script - check length when splitting string to array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using a bash script and I am trying to split a string with urls inside for example:

```
str=firsturl.com/123416 secondurl.com/634214
```

So these URLs are separated by spaces, I already used the `IFS` command to split the string and it is working great, I can iterate trough the two URLs with:

```
for url in $str; do
    #some stuff
done
```

But my problem is that I need to get how many items this splitting has, so for the `str` example it should return 2, but using this:

```
${#str[@]}
```

return the length of the string (`40` for the current example), I mean the number of characters, when I need to get `2`.

Also iterating with a counter won't work, because I need the number of elements before iterating the array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the string up into an array and use that instead:

```
str="firsturl.com/123416 secondurl.com/634214"
array=( $str )

echo "Number of elements: ${#array[@]}"
for item in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo "$item"
done
```

You should never have a space separated list of strings though. If you're getting them line by line from some other command, you can use a `while read` loop:

```
while IFS='' read -r url
do
  array+=( "$url" )
done
```

For properly encoded URLs, this probably won't make much of a difference, but in general, this will prevent glob expansion and some whitespace issues, and it's the canonical format that other commands (like `wget -i`) works with.

Comment: I am generating the urls from a python script, so I can change it and make it print several lines. How can I get them on an array? could you update that also please?

Comment: I ended up using a multiline file, but the array works great too.

Answer (score 5):

You should use something like this

```
declare -a a=( $str )
n=${#a[*]} # number of elements
```

Answer (score 3):

*Several ways:*

```
$ str="firsturl.com/123416 secondurl.com/634214"
```

#### bash array:

```
$ while read -a ary; do echo ${#ary[@]}; done <<< "$str"
2
```

#### awk:

```
$ awk '{print NF}' <<< "$str"
2
```

#### *nix utlity:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $(printf "$str" | wc -w)
2
```

#### bash without array:

```
$ set -- $str
$ echo ${#@}
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that will echo $* then that should provide the number of items to split.

```
count_params () { echo $#; }
```

Then passing $str to this function will give you the result

```
str="firsturl.com/123416 secondurl.com/634214"
count_params $str
```